# Repeating Logcat message after implementing a progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, logcat

I have implemented the use of a Progress bar within my app. When ever i navigate to the activity containing the progress bar i get a repeating Logcat message:

```
D/ProgressBar: setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
D/ProgressBar: mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
```

This is the first time i have came across this message, can someone please help me explain what it means exactly - is it an error/misuse of the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D/ anything in logcat stands for Debug, which simply means the Progress Bar is outputting information to help you debug it, you're using it just fine.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#filteringOutput

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. I was the first time i came across this so i wasn't sure what was happening. I appreciate the help.